# how to put generics in Supplier

Tags: java, generics

What is wrong with this:

```
public static final <T> Supplier<Map<Task, T>> TASK = () -> new EnumMap<>(Task.class);
```

I get this error:

```
Syntax error on tokens, ReferenceType expected instead
```

How can I add generics to this supplier?

Comment: Maybe you can a bit more code, so that we get a better overview.

Comment: There are 2 different types in there, `Tasks` vs`Task`

Comment: sorry was a typing error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
public static final <T> Supplier<Map<Task, T>> mapFactory() {
        return () -> new EnumMap<>(Task.class);
}
```

But yes, there is no need for supplier:

```
public static final <T> Map<Task, T> mapFactory() {
        return new EnumMap<>(Task.class);
}
```

Comment: Why declare it as returning a supplier, though? You could just declare it as a regular method, and refer to it as `YourClass::mapFactory` when you need a supplier.

Comment: However, if I want to write it as a function, I am wondering why the following is not possible: `public static final <T> Supplier<Map<Task, T>> mapFactory = () -> new EnumMap<Map<Task, T>>(Task.class);`

Comment: because you can't declare a generic field (that is, a field with its own type variable).